# Radio button background color with Chrome and WebGL <canvas>

Tags: javascript, css, radio-button, webgl, three.js

When using the WebGL renderer from Three.js, radio buttons gain white backgrounds. It appears to only occur in Chrome.

Here's a fiddle showing the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/5pL8v/328/

Is there any, and if so preferably CSS, fix to this?

Example code:

```
<style>
body {
    background: black;
}
</style>

<script>
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").append(renderer.domElement);
});
</script>

<input type="radio">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not able to see the problem OSX / Chrome beta. However, it is probably related to the rendering of widgets in native style by default and your operating system version. You can disable this in WebKit browsers using `-webkit-appearance: none`.

Example how to replace radio button with a green square:

```
body {
    background: black;
    color: white;
}

input[type=radio] {
    background: green;
    color: yellow;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}

input[type=radio]:checked {
    background: red;
}
```

I suggest you style radio buttons in platform-neutral way if they break on you. Here is one tutorial: http://www.wufoo.com/2011/06/13/custom-radio-buttons-and-checkboxes/

Comment: Thank you. I ultimately decided to modify your approach and hide the radio buttons and leave the labels with enable/disable effects.